# What type of ref is CreateableSelect in react-select in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I try to give the select a ref ,but not working. What is the correct type of ref in CreatableSelect
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it is SelectInstance :

```js
import {
  GroupBase,
  SelectInstance
} from "react-select";
//...
interface IOption {
//...
}
// Replace true by false if you don't want it multi
const containerRef = React.createRef<SelectInstance<IOption, true, GroupBase<IOption>>>();
```